# Everyone vs their

Tags: plural-forms, singular

Is my choice of words correct for the following sentence?

> So **everyone** on the site loses **their** login.

I got confused because '*everyone*' is singular but I am talking about more than 1 person when I say "*everyone on the site*" which is plural. The sentence sounds right but I just wanted to make sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When get confused, better use some safe alternative.

> So, *all those* on the site lose their login.

Nevertheless, if the early pronoun is *not gender specific*, the latter pronoun *can* have plural of it.

> If *a client* wants to come to your office, *they* should know the office timing. 
>   When *a person* starts drinking alcohol in excess quantity, *their* life is at risk.

More information [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/he-or-she-versus-they).

Comment: In contexts like these, it might be better to think of it as [singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) rather than "a special case when the latter pronoun can be plural".

Comment: @MarkS. True but it can be both as the answer will be the same! Singular *they* or a pronoun is an epicene.